# extracting columns, skipping certain rows in a file for data processing

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to process the `input.txt` using the `test.py` script to extract specific information as shown in the expected output. I have got the basic stub, but the regex apparently is not extracting the specific column details I am expecting. I have shown the expected output for your reference.

In general, I am looking for a `[XXXYY] {TAG}` pattern and once I find that pattern, if the next column starts with `J`, extract column 1, column 2 and (first 3 characters of) column3.  I am also interested in knowing how to remove certain lines after `[00033] GND` ( and `[00272] POS_3V3`) until I see the next `[XXXYY] {TAG}` pattern. I am restricted to using python 2.7.5, re and csv library and cannot use pandas.

###### input.txt

```
<<< Test List >>>
Mounting Hole                   MH1            APBC_MH_3.2x7cm
Mounting Hole                   MH2            APBC_MH_3.2x7cm
Mounting Hole                   MH3            APBC_MH_3.2x7cm
Mounting Hole                   MH4            APBC_MH_3.2x7cm

[00001] DEBUG_SCAR_RX
        J1         B30     PIO37          PASSIVE     TRA6-70-01.7-R-4-7-F-UG
        R2         2       2              PASSIVE     4.7kR

[00002] DEBUG_SCAR_TX
        J1         B29     PIO36          PASSIVE     TRA6-70-01.7-R-4-7-F-UG

[00003] DYOR_DAT_0
        J2         B12     APB10_CC_P     PASSIVE     TRA6-70-01.7-R-4-7-F-UG

[00033] GND
        DP1        5       5              PASSIVE     MECH, DIP_SWITCH, FFFN-04F-V
        DP1        6       6              PASSIVE     MECH, DIP_SWITCH, FFFN-04F-V
        DP1        7       7              PASSIVE     MECH, DIP_SWITCH, FFFN-04F-V

[00271] POS_3.3V_INH
        Q2         3       DRAIN          PASSIVE     2N7002
        R34        2       2              PASSIVE     4.7kR

[00272] POS_3V3
        J1         B13     FETO_FAT       PASSIVE     TRA6-70-01.7-R-4-7-F-UG
        J1         B14     FETO_FAT       PASSIVE     TRA6-70-01.7-R-4-7-F-UG
        J2         B59     FETO_HDB       PASSIVE     TRA6-70-01.7-R-4-7-F-UG
```

###### test.py

```
import re

# Read the input file
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.readlines()

# Process the data and extract the required information
result = []
component_name = ""
for line in content:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith("["):
        s = re.sub(r"([\[0-9]+\]) (\w+)$", r"\2", line)
    elif line.startswith("J"):
        sp = re.sub(r"^(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)", r"\1\2", line)
        print("%s\t%s" % (s, sp))
```

###### output

```
DEBUG_SCAR_RX   J1B30          PASSIVE     TRA6-70-01.7-R-4-7-F-UG
DEBUG_SCAR_TX   J1B29          PASSIVE     TRA6-70-01.7-R-4-7-F-UG
DYOR_DAT_0  J2B12     PASSIVE     TRA6-70-01.7-R-4-7-F-UG
POS_3V3 J1B13       PASSIVE     TRA6-70-01.7-R-4-7-F-UG
POS_3V3 J1B14       PASSIVE     TRA6-70-01.7-R-4-7-F-UG
POS_3V3 J2B59       PASSIVE     TRA6-70-01.7-R-4-7-F-UG
```

###### expected

```
DEBUG_SCAR_RX   J1 B30 PIO
DEBUG_SCAR_TX   J1 B29 PIO
DYOR_DAT_0  J2 B12 APB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use:

```
import re

TAGS = ['DEBUG_SCAR_RX', 'DEBUG_SCAR_TX', 'DYOR_DAT_0']

data = []
with open('input.txt') as file:
    for row in file:
        row = row.strip()       
        if row.startswith('['):
            tag = row.split(']')[1].strip()
        elif row == '':
            continue
        else:
            cols = re.split('\s+', row)
            if cols[0].startswith('J') and tag in TAGS:
                data.append([tag, cols[0], cols[1], cols[2][:3]])
```

Output:

```
# '2.7.18 (default, Jan 23 2023, 08:22:06) \n[GCC 12.2.0]'
>>> data
[['DEBUG_SCAR_RX', 'J1', 'B30', 'PIO'],
 ['DEBUG_SCAR_TX', 'J1', 'B29', 'PIO'],
 ['DYOR_DAT_0', 'J2', 'B12', 'APB']]
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to run your script and having an issue at the following line.   File "test3.py", line 14
    c1, c2, c3, *_ = re.split('\s+', row)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Still have an issue. File "test4.py", line 14, in <module>
    c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 = re.split('\s+', row)
ValueError: need more than 4 values to unpack

Comment: strangely on 2.7.5, I get the following result [['DEBUG_SCAR_RX', 'J1', 'B30', 'PAS'], ['DEBUG_SCAR_TX', 'J1', 'B29', 'PAS'], ['DYOR_DAT_0', 'J2', 'B12', 'PAS']]
The last column value extracted seems wrong. I think I have fixed it now.

Comment: @Corralien The code does **not** produce the stated output due to *cols[3]*

Comment: Sorry for that. I fixed it.. it was `cols[2]`

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need *re* for something so trivial.

Just read the input file one line at a time. Check if a line starts with left bracket. If it does, save the key value. Read the next line and plot into tokens. Check first character of the first token for 'J'. Print data as required:

```
with open('/Volumes/G-Drive/input.txt') as data:
    for line in data:
        if line.startswith('['):
            k = line.split()[-1]
            dl = next(data).split()
            if len(dl) > 2 and dl[0][0] == 'J':
                print(k, dl[0], dl[1], dl[2][:3])
```

**Output:**

```
DEBUG_SCAR_RX J1 B30 PIO
DEBUG_SCAR_TX J1 B29 PIO
DYOR_DAT_0 J2 B12 APB
POS_3V3 J1 B13 FET
```

Comment: Thanks, I just shown a subset of my input.txt. Your output still doesn't match my expected output.

Comment: @user2532296 In that case you probably want to explain the "rules" for what data you want to extract and exactly how the output should be presented

Comment: Sorry, if it was not clear from my description. Since another user understood my question and gave me an answer that was close to what I was expecting and I have accepted his answer. I will consider the case to be closed. But will make sure the rules are explained clearly in my future questions.

Comment: @user2532296 So you accepted an answer that doesn't actually produce the required output. Interesting